# Logrotate, my custom.conf file is not disposing old log files

Tags: logrotate

my custom.conf file for logrotate is only performing the renaming of old files but not disposing them after my maxage day. i can see it rotating the files. the custom.conf file is saved to /etc/logrotate.d/ directory. can someone please tell me if i am missing something here?
It just continues to add previous dates *.log-20180428-20180430-20180502-20180504 at the end of my log file.

Here is the custom.conf file (Note: directory_name path is a mounted drive.)

```
/directory_name/*/*/*.log* 
/directory_name/*/*.log* 
{
    daily
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 4
    ifempty
    maxage 4
    nocreate
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd-ng.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: Maybe `*.log*` should be just `*.log` without the ending `*`. This is probably the cause of why ever more dates are added to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/logrotate.conf` file should not start and end with `{` and `}` like that.

And `maxage` and `rotate` is probably not needed both (I always just use `rotate`, never `maxage`).

Before `{` there should be a file name, like this:

```
/var/log/mylog {
...
}
```

You should probably add and change files in the `/etc/logrotate.d` folder instead of changing the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file. (Protects better against automatic changes on system upgraded I think, and cleaner)

Comment: i have edited my subject line and original comments for clarity.